How to configure debugging for .NET Framework 3.5/4.8 in Visual Studio Code?
I’m transitioning from Visual Studio to Visual Studio Code for .NET Framework 3.5 and 4.8 projects. While setting up my environment, I’m encountering issues with configuring debugging and managing certain project files.
Specifically, I am stuck on:

Configuring the debugger to work with .NET Framework 3.5/4.8
projects.
Editing .resx files while ensuring that designer files are
updated automatically.
Managing .dbml files and ensuring their associated designer files
remain consistent.
Running unit tests in a way that's integrated and efficient.

How can I set up Visual Studio Code to debug .NET Framework 3.5/4.8 projects and handle .resx and .dbml files effectively?

I'm sure everyone's first question will be: why?

Are you trying to actively make your life miserable? It's one thing to entertain support for one or some legacy projects you are not able or allowed to upgrade. But making that even harder seems weird to me.
